# If an user is using app, then how to stop showing notification?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am designing an android app which uses notification.
Before this, I was using a full screen activity, so if a notification came, in full view I didn't get any alert.
Now I am using a blank activity with notifications enabled.
I don't want to show notifications when I am already inside the app (like skype).
Or else, I want to cancel them immediately once flashed.
How to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a superclass for all of your activities and track the state of the app. If all activities are in stopped state - app in the background, otherwise - in the foreground. In `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods of your super activity you can increment and decrement the number of visible activites.

```
public class SuperActivity extends Activity {
    private static int sVisibleActivitiesCount;

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        sVisibleActivitiesCount++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStart();
        sVisibleActivitiesCount--;
    }

    public static boolean isAppInForeground() {
        return sVisibleActivitiesCount > 0;
    }
}
```

Now you can check somewhere for an application status and not create notification if `SuperActivity.isAppInForeground` returns true.

The second approach is to use [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) (min API 14) for monitoring activities lifecycle and track application state in a single place without having a super class for all activities. So I would rather use this approach if your app has minSdkVersion="14".

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the running processes list and check if the one in foreground is your app.

```
private boolean isAppInForeground() {

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> mRunningProcesses = mActivityManager
            .getRunningAppProcesses();
    Iterator<RunningAppProcessInfo> i = mRunningProcesses.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo = i.next();

        if (runningAppProcessInfo.uid == getApplicationInfo().uid && runningAppProcessInfo.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) 
            {
                return true;
           }
       }
    return false;
}
```